# How to connect asmq channel in remote machine. amqp.connect()

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqplib

i am able to connect to asmq channel using rabbitmq in my local machine using below code.

but i want to connect to this channel in different machine and receive data.

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function (err, conn) {});

Comment: So what happens when you substitute `localhost` with the name of that remote machine?

Comment: i am getting below error                                              
conn.createChannel(function (err, ch) {
       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createChannel' of undefined

Comment: Code : 
amqp.connect('amqp://172.22.25.64', function (err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function (err, ch) {

Comment: Be careful, you cannot access to RabbitMQ with the default user (guest) from another host (only from localhost).